# Nested for loop to enter and exit multiple directories Bash script

Tags: bash, loops, nested

As an example, I have 7 directories each containing 4 files. The 4 files follow the following naming convention name_S#_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz. The sed command is to partially keep the unique file name.

I have a nested for loop in order to enter a directory and perform a command, exit the directory and proceed to the next directory. Everything seems to be working beautifully, however the code gets stuck on the last directory looping 4 times.

```
for f in /completepath/*
do
    [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && echo Entering into $f
    for y in `ls *.fastq.gz | sed 's/_L00[1234]_R1_001.fastq.gz//g' | sort -u`
    do
        echo ${y}
    done
done
```

Example output-

```
Entering into /completepath/m_i_cast_avpv_1
iavpvcast1_S6
Entering into /completepath/m_i_cast_avpv_2
iavpvcast2_S6
Entering into /completepath/m_i_int_avpv_1
iavpvint1_S5
Entering into /completepath/m_i_int_avpv_2
iavpvint2_S5
Entering into /completepath/m_p_cast_avpv_1
pavpvcast1_S8
Entering into /completepathd/m_p_int_avpv_1
pavpvint1_S7
Entering into /completepath/m_p_int_avpv_2
pavpvint2_S7
pavpvint2_S7
pavpvint2_S7
pavpvint2_S7
```

Any recommendations of how to correctly exit the inner loop?

Comment: tried checking what `ls *.fastq.gz | sed 's/_L00[1234]_R1_001.fastq.gz//g' | sort -u` really outputs?

Comment: Add output of `find /completepath -ls` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `/completepath/` contains some entries that are not directories. When the loop over `/completepath/*` sees something that's not a directory, it doesn't enter it, thanks to the `[ -d $f ]` check.
But it still continues to run the next `for y in ...` loop.
At that point the script is still in the previous directory it has seen.

One way to solve that is to skip the rest of the loop when `$f` is not a directory:

```
if [ -d $f ]; then
    cd "$f" && echo Entering into $f
else
    continue
fi
```

There's an even better way. By writing `/completepath/*/` only directory entries will be matched, so you can simplify your loop to this:

```
for f in /completepath/*/
do
    cd "$f" && echo "Entering into $f" || { echo "Error: could not enter into $f"; continue; }
    for y in $(ls *.fastq.gz | sed 's/_L00[1234]_R1_001.fastq.gz//g' | sort -u)
    do
        echo ${y}
    done
done
```

Comment: Excellent. The explanation was very informative and modifying the complete path did the trick.